# Mouse click with GetAsyncStateKey

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to make a program that when you click, it uses `GetAsyncStateKey()` to know that you've clicked and makes the code click once more, like a double-clicker.

The problem is, I don't know anything about coding, so I tried to look at many codes and came up with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)) {
       mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
       Sleep(0);

       return 0;
    }
}
```

In my mind, when it opens, it should stay open, hence the `sleep`, then getting the part if I click, it clicks again. But in reality, when I open it, it closes immediately.

Can someone make it work for me?

Comment: What is `Sleep(0)` supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Making the program stay open until I want to close it? Maybe? I don't know

Comment: You need a loop.

Comment: A loop that will keep the program open?

Comment: ? Why can't I edit this question? I can edit all other questions. But for me there's no edit button here. It's not closed or so. Weird. Please also tag windows api.

Comment: *"Can someone make it work for me?"* is not a question that's on-topic. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program performs 1 operation and then exits. You need a loop to keep it alive, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    while (true) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0) {
           mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        Sleep(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```